# How to access to specific data in variable position in object php

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, object

I am trying to return the value of an object with array in php laravel, what I am doing to access the information is the following, which works correctly, but the problem comes when the information I need changes position for example from 21 to 22 I can not access because obviously in the node in which I try to find the information does not exist

EDIT:The position of the property I am trying to access can be in different positions, that's why I need to find it by the name UUID="" and not just put an IF, besides that as the object can have several arrays I can't search for it in the controller or it adds a new array.

my object :

[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5GER.png)

in my blade.php:

```html
   @foreach ($xml_objeto as $xml_objeto)
                    <tr>   
                    <td> {{ $xml_objeto[1]['Rfc'] }} </td> // works
                    <td> {{ current($xml_objeto)->UUID }} </td> // I tried but it does not work
                    <td>  {{ $xml_objeto[21]['UUID'] }} </td> // it works but when the data changes position from 21 to 22 it is no longer localized
                    <td>  {{ $xml_objeto[1]['Nombre'] }} </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

it should be noted that it is the only data with that name UUID=""  in my object.
thank you very much for all the help you can give me.

Comment: If the UUID property is inconsistent, You can use the null check.

Answer (score 0):

What does `$xml_objeto[21]['UUID']` return when it is no longer localized?

If it comes back as an empty string, or anything else other than what you want - you could check the other index.

For example:

```
{{ $xml_objeto[21]['UUID'] == '' ? $xml_objeto[22]['UUID'] : $xml_objeto[21]['UUID']; }}
```

Comment: That can be helpful, but as it could be dynamic, example ['UUID'] is passed to position (15) or (36), since there is no way to know how much content the xml has and in which position it can return the needed value

Answer (score 0):

You can try using null coalescing, it will print null or whatever you want if it doesn't find that index in the array

```html
<td>  {{ $xml_objeto[$key]['UUID'] ?? null}} </td> 

or

<td>  {{ $xml_objeto[21]['UUID'] ?? $xml_objeto[22]['UUID']}} </td>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment, I am not looking for it to be conditional, since it can be in many positions, rather I am looking to return that specific value in the position it is, since in the foreach it goes through many files with similar structure but with different amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not related to the position, there is only one of your XML objects that has the UUID property right? if it is then you need to loop on the objects to extract the UUID value

Comment: Is it correct, any example or documentation on how to do it in the blade?, because if I do it in the controller it adds it as a new array

Comment: you dont need to pass a new array if it is just a UUID value, also is not best practice to do any logic in the blade, the problem here there is object has a unique property